# Is there a Windows equivalent to $SHLVL?

Tags: linux, windows, cmd

I recently ran a 3rd party script that ran "cmd" inside of it, thus increasing the nesting depth of my cmd window (making my history and DOSKey macros unavailable in the process). So I was wondering if there's an equivalent of $SHLVL or some other way to determine this situation? I suppose I could just up-arrow to see if my history is still there, but someday I might need this from a script.

There does not appear to be anything different when I review the output of "set". Thanks!

Comment: If you did have an equivalent of $SHLVL, what would you do with it?

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, I don't have a need for it right now, I'm curious if such a thing exists for Windows. The situation described has definitely occurred, and I have used $SHLVL in bash scripts before.

Comment: It is probably easy enough to walk up the PPID tree. But that begs the question of how to count non-shell executables. Does x.exe which starts a shell count? Also, does $SHLVL count when a bash shell starts an sh shell which starts a ksh shell which starts...?

Comment: @catcat Are you joking or would you like me to flag your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Changed code to list PIDs.

**Edit 2** Changed code to output the level as `%errorlevel%`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleprocesslist

**CountConsoleProcess.vb**

```
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
Public Module MyApplication  

Public Declare Function GetConsoleProcessList Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef ProcessList as Integer, ByVal Count as Integer) As Integer

Public Sub Main ()
                Dim ProcessList(0 To 9) As Integer
                Dim Count As Integer
                Dim Ret As Integer
                Dim x as Integer
                Dim ColItems as Object
                Dim objWMIService As Object
                objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
                Count = 10
                'subtract one to account for this program
                Ret = GetConsoleProcessList(ProcessList(0), 10) - 1
                Console.Writeline("Level = " & Ret)

                For x = Ret  to 1 step -1
                    colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where ProcessID=" & ProcessList(x))
                    For Each objItem in colItems
                        Console.writeline("PID : " & objItem.ProcessID & "  Command line : " &  objItem.CommandLine)
                    Next
                Next
                Environment.ExitCode = Ret  
End Sub
End Module
```

**CountConsoleProcess.bat**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\CountConsoleProcess.vb" /debug:full /out:"%~dp0\CountConsoleProcess.exe" /target:exe 
pause
```

**ConsoleTest.Bat**

```
REM Showing error level
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleTest.bat"
Echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

And to use (after doing a `cmd /k` so their are two CMDs running). The first is the current PID.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cmd /k echo hello world
hello world

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleTest.bat"

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Console.exe"
Level = 2
PID : 6848  Command line : "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
PID : 7824  Command line : cmd  /k echo hello world

C:\Windows\system32>Echo 2
2    

C:\Windows\system32>
```

And to add the current folder to the path

**_AddThisFolderToPath.bat**

```
Setx path "%path%;%~dp0"
Pause
```

Comment: Works great - thanks! One nit: x has to be declared; added that and it now runs fine. Marking as answer.

Comment: @cniggeler You could have edited the answer yourself to add `dim x as integer`. I've about to do that anyway.